# TextView size is showing different when custom listview is scrolled

Tags: android, listview, scroll, text-size

In Listview adapter there is condition based textview text size is changing.

**condition 1:** if no value for discounted it must show only its price in (textview_price) and hide discounted value textview.(textview_price size= 18)

**condition 2:** if there is value for discounted price then it must show its price in (textview_price) and discounted value textview_discounted.(textview_price size= 15 and textview_discounted size=18).

[image]

As shown in above image i am setting visibility gone of textview_discount.
On first time it shows lsitview complete as i set textview size.But when i scroll lsitview its show as above in image not getting proper text size.and text size is=18 where text is big and some where textview size is 15.(problem in textView_price setTextSize not working properly)

adapter.java code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_booking_slot_hours,parent ,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv_hours = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hour);
        holder.textView_hour_am = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_hour_am);
        holder.textView_Price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Price);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
        String stringPrice = "1500";
        String stringDiscountedPrice = "1000"
           if (entity.getPay().equals("0")) {
                holder.textView_Price.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 18);
                holder.textView_Price.setText("Rs." + stringPrice);
                holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else if (entity.getPay().equals("1")){
            holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.textView_Price.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 15);
            holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 18));

            holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setText("Rs." + stringDiscountedPrice);
            holder.textView_Price.setText("Rs." + stringPrice, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }

    return convertView;
}
```

layout.xml for row:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_hour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_hour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="05:00"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_booking_hour_text"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_hour_am"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_hour"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=" pm"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_booking_hour_am"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout_hour">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_Discounted_Price"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Rs.4000"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_booking_hour_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_slot_price" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Discounted_Price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView_slot_arrow"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Rs.3000"
           android:textColor="@drawable/selector_booking_hour_text_discounted"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_slot_discount_price"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_slot_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/next" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i have edited my question and added post adapter code.can you help now? @kishorejethava

Comment: you have set condition on `inflater`  right ?

Comment: mean i am not getting you. i have puted condition where i have set textview values inside adapter and also in layout file(tried to remove values from layout.xml file but not worked).@kishorejethava

Comment: it is set textview text size completely when it is first time loaded but when i start scrolling list view it shows as in image displayed. thank you. @kishorejethava

Comment: posted xml code @kishorejethava

Answer (score 0):

try this modified code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_booking_slot_hours,parent ,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv_hours = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hour);
        holder.textView_hour_am = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_hour_am);
        holder.textView_Price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Price);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

           if (entity.getPay().equals("0")) {
            holder.textView_Price.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (entity.getPay().equals("1")) {
            holder.textView_Price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

           String stringPrice = "1500";
           String stringDiscountedPrice = "1000"
        if(!hasDiscount)//flag means your item has no discount

                holder.textView_Price.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 18);
                holder.textView_Price.setText("Rs." + stringPrice);
                holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {

                holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.textView_Price.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 15);
                holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 18));
                holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setText("Rs." + stringDiscountedPrice);
                holder.textView_Price.setText("Rs." + stringPrice, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i tried it, not worked already coded if condition i forgot to mention in code sorry for that,so i again edited my code. @kishore jethava

Comment: post your `xml` or see your list data value

Comment: it's working dude.! error is somewhere else. see your list data.

Comment: 1.)when there is both values exist in whole list for discounted value and price both in same list working great. 2.) when single textview price in same list  then also working great but 3.) when in list both type of values where some rows with both discount and price and some row only price then its not working in same list. @kishorejethava

Comment: yes but only for first time when i scroll lsitview textview text size some where set to 18 not 15 and some where 15 not 18.

Comment: problem is this  `android:textSize="@dimen/text_slot_discount_price"`. when you have not discount . default size will set

Comment: remove `android:textSize` from both `TextView`

Comment: no problem in text_price not in discount which is in black colour textview discounted in red colour. thanks for suggestion i will try in your way

Comment: yes when i removed that text size from both textview problem is same but in font size there is not that much variation like what i getting but still there is variation in font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

When I Logged textview_price text size by `textView_Price.getTextSize()`
I am getting some random position of row's "textview_price.getTextSize()=36" and "textview_discount_price.getTextSize()=36" and where only textView_Price is showing on that psotion row I am getting "textView_Price.getTextSize()=30" randomly when I am scrolling lsitview.

**Note**: I was getting textview size in form of textviewSize*2. **example:** if textview textSize=18 then 18*2 = 36.0. why I don't know.

So,finally in if{...}else{...} condition i change the code

```
if (entity.getPay().equals("0")) {
            holder.textView_Price.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 18);
            holder.textView_Price.setText("Rs." + stringPrice);
            holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(holder.textView_Price.getTextSize()==30.0)
                {
                    holder.textView_Price.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 18);

                }
    } else if (entity.getPay().equals("1")){
        holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.textView_Price.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 15);
        holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 18));
        holder.textView_Discounted_Price.setText("Rs." + stringDiscountedPrice);
        holder.textView_Price.setText("Rs." + stringPrice, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            if(holder.textView_Price.getTextSize()==36.0)
            {
                holder.textView_Price.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 15);

            }
    }
```